# Perform calculations using variables from two independent matrices

Tags: r, matrix

I have got two matrices.

Matrix 1

```
     id1 id2 id3 id4 id5
row1 0.4 0.5 0.2 0.1 0.3
```

Matrix 2

```
     id1 id2 id3 id4 id5
row1 1.1 1.2 1.3 4.1 4.0
row2 3.4 2.6 1.2 3.2 2.1
row3 4.5 6.2 1.1 1.3 3.1
```

I am trying to match the column vectors by ids and run the following formula for each column in matrix 1 and 2 independently of the remaining column ids

```
(matrix1$id*matrix2$id)^2+2(matrix1$id*matrix2$id)+(1-matrix1$id)^2
```

Please suggest a way to loop this function across the IDs after matching based on column Ids.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mat1 <- matrix(nrow=1,ncol=5)
mat1 <- as.matrix(t(c(0.4, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3)))

mat2 <- matrix(nrow=3, ncol=5)
mat2[1,] <- c(1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 4.1, 4.0)
mat2[2,] <- c(3.4, 2.6, 1.2, 3.2, 2.1)
mat2[3,] <- c(4.5, 6.2, 1.1, 1.3, 3.1)

result <- matrix(nrow = 3, ncol = 5)

for(i in 1:ncol(mat1)){
  result[,i] <- t((mat1[,i]*mat2[,i])^2 + 2*(mat1[,i]*mat2[,i]) + (1 - mat1[,i])^2)  
}

result

       [,1]  [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]
[1,] 1.4336  1.81 1.2276 1.7981 4.3300
[2,] 4.9296  4.54 1.1776 1.5524 2.1469
[3,] 7.2000 16.06 1.1284 1.0869 3.2149
```

You can also use column names instead of indices or send the equation in the `for` loop to a function and use `apply`.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`t()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/t.html) and fully vectorized arithmetic (assumes columns correspond):

```
x <- t(m2)*c(m1); t(x^2+2*x+(1-c(m1))^2);
##         id1   id2    id3    id4    id5
## row1 1.4336  1.81 1.2276 1.7981 4.3300
## row2 4.9296  4.54 1.1776 1.5524 2.1469
## row3 7.2000 16.06 1.1284 1.0869 3.2149
```

---

Using [`sapply()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html) over the column names:

```
sapply(colnames(m1),function(cn) { x <- m1[,cn]*m2[,cn]; x^2+2*x+(1-m1[,cn])^2; });
##         id1   id2    id3    id4    id5
## row1 1.4336  1.81 1.2276 1.7981 4.3300
## row2 4.9296  4.54 1.1776 1.5524 2.1469
## row3 7.2000 16.06 1.1284 1.0869 3.2149
```

---

**Data**

```
m1 <- as.matrix(data.frame(id1=0.4,id2=0.5,id3=0.2,id4=0.1,id5=0.3,row.names='row1'));
m2 <- as.matrix(data.frame(id1=c(1.1,3.4,4.5),id2=c(1.2,2.6,6.2),id3=c(1.3,1.2,1.1),id4=c(4.1,3.2,1.3),id5=c(4,2.1,3.1),row.names=c('row1','row2','row3')));
```